# Get Unique Results from NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to return an `NSFetchRequest` with distinct values. This is what I have:

```
class Tag: NSManagedObject {
    static let entityName = "\(Tag.self)"

    static var allTagsRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Tag.entityName)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]
        return request
    }()

    static var uniqueTagsRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: Tag.entityName)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]
        request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
        request.returnsDistinctResults = true
        return request
    }()
}
```

The `allTagsRequest` returns properly, i.e. it returns all of the tags stored in CoreData - even the duplicates. I want the `uniqueTagsRequest` to return only unique tags, but when I do, the tableView doesn't populate. Here is my tableView code:

```
class SortableDataSource<SortType: CustomTitleConvertible>: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource where SortType: NSManagedObject {

    let kReuseIdentifier = "sortableItemCell"

    fileprivate let fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>

    var results: [SortType] {
        return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [SortType]
    }

    init(fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>, managedObjectContext moc: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        super.init()
        executeFetch()
    }

    func executeFetch() {
        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(
                title: "Error",
                message: "\(error.debugDescription)",
                preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "Ok",
                style: .cancel,
                handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 2 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0: return 1
        case 1: return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count ?? 0
        default: return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: kReuseIdentifier)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) {
        case (0, 0):
            cell.textLabel?.text = "All \(SortType.self)s"
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        case (1, _):
            guard let sortItem = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?[indexPath.row] as? SortType else { break}
            cell.textLabel?.text = sortItem.title
        default: break
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

And sort controller:

```
@objc fileprivate func presentSortController() {
        let tagDataSource = SortableDataSource<Tag>(fetchRequest: Tag.uniqueTagsRequest, managedObjectContext: CoreDataController.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext)
        let sortItemSelector = SortItemSelector(sortItems: tagDataSource.results)
        let sortController = PhotoSortListController(dataSource: tagDataSource, sortItemSelector: sortItemSelector)

        sortController.onSortSelection = { checkedItems in
            if !checkedItems.isEmpty {
                var predicates = [NSPredicate]()
                for tag in checkedItems {
                    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K CONTAINS %@", "tags.title", tag.title)
                    predicates.append(predicate)
                }
                let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
                self.dataSource.performFetch(withPredicte: compoundPredicate)
            } else {
                self.dataSource.performFetch(withPredicte: nil)
            }
        }

        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sortController)

        present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was me, I would populate a local array with the `allTagsRequest` and have the `NSFetchedResultsController` feed that. Then I would have that local array feed the tableview.

That way, when you need the unique list you can just do the little trick where you convert the array into an `NSSet` and then back to an array (this removes duplicates). When you're ready to get the whole list again, you can just refetch from the original and reload the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud, but if you set the resultType to

```
request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
```

will this really work?

```
let tagDataSource = SortableDataSource<Tag>(fetchRequest: Tag.uniqueTagsRequest,...)
```

---

```
var results: [SortType] {
    return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [SortType]
}
```

Won´t the `fetchedObjects` be of `[String:Any]` ?

Comment: You're right - and that's part of my problem. If I don't make the resultType .dictionaryResultType then the returnDistinctResults won't work. If I use the .dictionaryResultType, then I can't populate the table.

Comment: I guess I'm wondering how to return distinct results without the dictionaryResultType